# purchased web app not showing up in app parts

Tags: sharepoint-online

So I have purchased a web app. It has been added to the app catalog site. This app has also been added to site contents for my site. For some reason when I go to a page and try to add this app to the page it is not listed in the list of app parts.

Tools:

SharePoint Online, (I am a tenant admin)

back story:

I had this app on the site at one point but I removed it (idk why). I believe that SharePoint is still referencing the old app that I removed and will not update it's status when I re-added it. (i don't think custom identifiers are created for each new instance of the app)

I had this issue with a custom app that I added but I had access to the source code so I simply changed it's name and re-added it. (that worked) but since this app is not mines and I got it from SP app store I cannot change anything.

Is there any way to get SharePoint to release all references to an app after I remove it?

steps taken:

removed the app from site contents,

removed the license in the admin panel,

removed the app in the app catalog site,

waited.....

re-added the app

I realize that this question may have been asked before, but from what I have seen in other posts the problem was never really resolved.